# jQuery fadeOut not working second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery fadeOut is not running the second time.

```
 <div id="clickme">click here</div>
```

JS

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#feedback').html('hello world').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I have tried without remove; it's not working in that case either.

Comment: It doesn't work because you remove `#feedback` after the first click.

Comment: @ pramod - its not working dear

Comment: @dfsq - i have tried with out remove also

Comment: after clicking am appending also

Comment: can you please paste the full code (including the append JS section) in which the 2nd remove should work?

Comment: @tutipute - thnks for ur co-operation, one guy has given the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Do not remove the element, instead hide it.

2/ You need to show the element before fadeOut, it does not fade out if it is already hidden.
( or use `animate` with proper parameters )

http://jsfiddle.net/QmajJ/

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#feedback').html('hello world').show().fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what are you trying to do but its not working the second time because you are removing the element from the first time

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#feedback').html('hello world').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove(); // <----- you are removing the feedback element so in the second time there will be no "$('#feedback')" because of that its not working 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with unbind your click control properly

```
$('#clickme').unbind().click(function() {
   //your content
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have removed the element you want to be animated

```
$('#feedback').html('hello world').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```